# CasperJS - Screen capture returns black image & test case does not find element when target url is not localhost

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I am using CasperJs along with Phantomjs 1.9.8. I am testing a site which uses windows authentication. I am testing a version which is deployed on a remote server and locally.

Here is the test case.

```
var baseUrl = "http://SNG09034236:9999";   //For testing app on remote server

//var baseUrl = "http://localhost:9999";  //For testing app locally

casper.options.viewportSize = {
  width: 1024,
  height: 800
}

casper.pageSetting = {userName: 'myuid', password:pwd};

casper.options.waitTimeout = 5000;

casper.on('resource.requested', function(requestData, networkRequest) {
     //console.log('Request (#' + requestData.id + '): ' + JSON.stringify(requestData) + "\n");
});
casper.on("resource.received", function(response){
    // console.log('Response (#' + response.id + ', stage "' + response.stage + '"): ' + JSON.stringify(response) + "\n");
});



casper.test.begin('Connecting to application', function suite(test) {
   casper.start(baseUrl, function() {
       document.querySelector("body").style.height = "700px";
       this.echo("TITLE : ====> " + this.getTitle());
       this.captureSelector('c:\\temp\\myImage.png', 'html');
  })
   .then(function(){
     test.assertTitle("My app", "Title is correct");
   })
   .waitForSelector("#showUser",
       function success() {
           test.assertExists("#showUser", "Shadow button found");
           this.click("#showUser");
       },
       function fail() {
         console.log('Shadow button NOT found');
           test.assertExists("#showUser");
   })
   .waitForSelector("#show-window-body",
       function success() {
           test.assertExists("#show-window-body", "Show div found");
           this.click("#show-window-body");
       },
       function fail() {
           test.assertExists("#show-window-body");
   })
   .waitForSelector("input[name='search_user-inputEl']",
       function success() {
          test.assertExists("input[name='search_user-inputEl']", "Show text box found");
          this.click("input[name='search_user-inputEl']");
          this.sendKeys('#search_user-inputEl', 'tomjspn3');
       },
       function fail() {
           test.assertExists("input[name='search_user-inputEl']");
   })
   .waitForSelector("li",
       function success() {
           test.assertExists("li", "User found");
           this.click("li");
       },
       function fail() {
           test.assertExists("li", "User NOT found");
   })
  .run(function() {
    casper.echo("TESTS COMPLETED");
    casper.exit();
  });
});
```

**Issues:**

1. `this.captureSelector('c:\\temp\\myImage.png', 'html');` always returns a black image file (for site hoested locally and remotely ). But if test another site (google.com etc), I get the correct screenshot.
2. In the test case I am searching for `showUser` div. When the run the test case targeting a site which is hosted on local box, everything works fine and when I run same test case by changing the URL to a remote server, system cannot find the `showUser` div and does not produce any result.

Actually after adding the various hooks I can see following error when connecting to remote site:

```
Response (#1, stage "end"): {"contentType":null,"headers":[],"id":1,"redirectUR
":null,"stage":"end","status":401,"statusText":"Authorization Required","time":
2015-12-03T17:26:15.691Z","url":"http://SNG09034236:9999/"}

ResourceError: {
    "errorCode": 5,
    "errorString": "Operation canceled",
    "id": 0,
    "url": "http://SNG09034236:9999/"
}
```

I have also changed `casper.pageSetting to casper.options.pageSetting`

Comment: (1) `document.querySelector("body").style.height = "700px";` isn't doing anything, because it's not in the page context. (2) There is no such thing as `casper.pageSetting`. You mean `casper.options.pageSettings`. (3)  Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-2_caspererrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: @ArtjomB. : I have updated the question

Comment: It's `casper.options.pageSettings` not `casper.options.pageSetting`

Comment: @ArtjomB. even after using `casper.options.pageSettings`, I am getting same error. I also dont understand why I am not able tp capture the image of the site even when running the test locally.